# Do I need to have a full node to create an online bitcoin wallet

Tags: e-wallet

I am creating an online exchange website. I need to have a reliable bitcoin wallet on my website.

Do I need to have a full node to create an online bitcoin wallet?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a reliable wallet, then you should run a full node rather than trusting a third party service or running a light node.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is not an essential requirement to run a full node but, for an Exchange website, it would seem quite unusual not to.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want trust third party services: yes.